# Logistic Regression Implementation

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, logistic-regression

I am having some difficulties in implementing logistic regression, in terms of how should I should proceed stepwise. According to what I have done so far I am implementing it in the following way:

- First taking `theta` equal to the number of features and making it a `n*1` vector of zeros. Now using this `theta` to compute the the following
  `htheta = sigmoid(theta' * X');`
  `theta = theta - (alpha/m) * sum (htheta' - y)'*X`
- Now using the `theta` computed in the first step to compute the cost function
  `J= 1/m *((sum(-y*log(htheta))) - (sum((1-y) * log(1 - htheta)))) + lambda/(2*m) * sum(theta).^2`
- In the end computing the gradient
  `grad = (1/m) * sum ((sigmoid(X*theta) - y')*X);`

As i am taking `theta` to be zero. I am getting same value of `J` throughout the vector, is this the right output?

Comment: Could you provide a minimum working example, for instance using some dummy data. You can produce it like this: `y=randi(2,[10,1])-1` & `X=[ones(10,1) randn([10,1])`. From what I can see: the cost function should change as you update `theta`. However, it is unclear why you compute the gradient twice (i.e., once at updating `theta` and in the final step).

Comment: @zundertj actually that is the part i am also unclear about. If you can tell me which thing to compute first and why, that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are computing the gradient in the last step, while it has been computed before in the computation of the new `theta`. Moreover, your definition of the cost function contains a regularization parameter, but this is not incorporated in the gradient computation. A working version without the regularization:

```
% generate dummy data for testing
y=randi(2,[10,1])-1;
X=[ones(10,1) randn([10,1])];

% initialize
alpha = 0.1;
theta = zeros(1,size(X,2));
J = NaN(100,1);

% loop a fixed number of times => can improve this by stopping when the
% cost function no longer decreases
htheta = sigmoid(X*theta');
for n=1:100
    grad = X' * (htheta-y); % gradient
    theta = theta - alpha*grad'; % update theta
    htheta = sigmoid(X*theta');
    J(n) = sum(-y'*log(htheta)) - sum((1-y)' * log(1 - htheta)); % cost function
end
```

If you now plot the cost function, you will see (except for randomness) that it converges after about 15 iterations.